# Get Tag value while tapped Button in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, swiftui

In **SwiftUI** I have created a loop of button.

I have to get tag value when button was tapped.

I have tried many times. I cant able to get which button was tapped

```
HStack(spacing: 1) {
         ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { j in
                            Button(action: {
                                // need button Tag
                               print("Tapped Button Tag:")
                            }, label: {
                                    Text("")
                            })
                            .tag("\(j)")
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not needed in tag, it is possible to do this directly, like

```
HStack(spacing: 1) {
         ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { j in
                Button(action: {
                    // j is available here from context
                   print("Tapped Button Tag: \(j)")  // << here !!
                }, label: {
                        Text("")
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: Most of the loops will not have count. Most will be initialised  by object array. How to get tag if loop is made be object array rather than integer range?